# inconsistent behavior of heatmap color

Tags: python, deep-learning, heatmap

I am following this nice notebook to understand what my model is learning, : 
https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-with-python-notebooks/blob/master/5.4-visualizing-what-convnets-learn.ipynb

The issue is that when I plot the heatmap, I have the same kind of image as on the github (i.e. with yellow showing the part the model is using to asses the class)

```
heatmap = np.maximum(heatmap, 0) heatmap /= np.max(heatmap)
plt.matshow(heatmap) plt.show()
```

[image]

But when I do the following, just like the github:

```
# We use cv2 to load the original image
img = img_aug

# We resize the heatmap to have the same size as the original image
heatmap = cv2.resize(heatmap, (img.shape[1], img.shape[0]))

# We convert the heatmap to RGB
heatmap = np.uint8(255 * heatmap)

# We apply the heatmap to the original image
heatmap = cv2.applyColorMap(heatmap, cv2.COLORMAP_JET)

# 0.4 here is a heatmap intensity factor
superimposed_img = heatmap * 0.4 + img
plt.imshow(superimposed_img.astype(int));
```

I have an image where now the part that the network is looking at is blue (color reversed compared to the first picture), while in the github its still like the initial heatmap. I think I am misssing a detail there.... could any one give me a hint?
Thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: So you want the colors on the color map to be reversed?

Comment: thanks Dodge for your answer. No, I dont care about that, I would like to udnerstand how is it possible that my color egt reverse while in the link I posted its not reversed (i..e the final image has orange-pixel to be most important, while I have blue)